# Java and Tomcat - CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled

Tags: java, tomcat, compiler-construction, code-caching

**My Situation**

- I have developed a web service for document analysis
- This web service reads txt and pdf documents
- For reading pdf files I am using a java library developed by my university advisor
- I am using Java 7
- I am currently deploying it on Tomcat v7.0
- If I generate a war file from my application and host it on a local tomcat on my pc, or if I start my application on tomcat via eclipse ee, the reading of a pdf file makes no problem

**My Problem**

- I have set up myself a little server (not the best hardware, dual core cpu, 4g ram), installed tomcat, java and the rest that seemed necessary to me.
- When I now deploy a war file on the servers tomcat using the tomcat manager everything works fine until I try to let the application read a pdf file.
- After the application has read several pages I get an error that the CodeCache has become full and the compile has been disabled because of this.

**Example error output during a pdf import**

This log shows how the pdf is being imported and on some point the error messages start. I have marked the error message bold.

...

May 31, 2012 11:15:40 AM infovis.structure.pdf.PDFImport process INFO:
Processing Page 13

May 31, 2012 11:15:40 AM infovis.structure.pdf.PDFImport process INFO: Processing Page 14

May 31, 2012 11:15:41 AM infovis.structure.pdf.PDFImport process INFO: Processing Page 15

**`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Try increasing the code cache size using -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize= Code Cache  [0x00007fa43437e000, 0x00007fa4347fe000, 0x00007fa43737e000)  total_blobs=1858 nmethods=1318 adapters=490 free_code_cache=44631Kb largest_free_block=45618688 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Try increasing the code cache size using -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize= Code Cache  [0x00007fa43437e000, 0x00007fa4347fe000, 0x00007fa43737e000)  total_blobs=1859 nmethods=1318 adapters=490 free_code_cache=44631Kb largest_free_block=45618688`**

May 31, 2012 11:16:19 AM infovis.structure.pdf.PDFImport process INFO: Processing Page 16

May 31, 2012 11:16:20 AM infovis.structure.pdf.PDFImport process INFO: Processing Page 17

**`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Try increasing the code cache size using -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize= Code Cache  [0x00007fa43437e000, 0x00007fa4347fe000, 0x00007fa43737e000)  total_blobs=1860 nmethods=1318 adapters=490 free_code_cache=44630Kb largest_free_block=45618688 May 31, 2012 11:17:07 AM infovis.structure.pdf.PDFImport process INFO: Processing Page 18 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: CodeCache is full. Compiler has been disabled. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Try increasing the code cache size using -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize= Code Cache  [0x00007fa43437e000, 0x00007fa4347fe000, 0x00007fa43737e000)  total_blobs=1861 nmethods=1318 adapters=490 free_code_cache=44633Kb largest_free_block=45618688`**

and so on...

**What I have tried so far**

I have tried to change the cache sizes in the tomcat configuration on my server (I'm not the best in working with the linux shell). I have tried to  increase the CodeCache Size, as well as the size of the other caches but the problem still occurs. I have checked my code for possible leaks but did not find any yet (Remember, if I start it via eclipse I dont get this message, so this might indicate a tomcat(?) configuration problem). I have also tried to set the parameter "UseCodeCacheFlushing" that should enforce to empty the code cache when it's becoming full, but somehow it doesn't effect the applications breakdown.

**My tomcat server configuration**

I have read that the default CodeCache size is 32MB or 64MB when it's a 64 bit application. I tried reserving 512mb (maybe I did something wrong in the configuration?) but the problem of course happened again.

> You may pass JVM startup parameters to Java here. If unset, the
> default options will be: -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m
> -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
>
> Use "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" to enable the CMS garbage collector
> (improved response time). If you use that option and you run Tomcat on
> a machine with exactly one CPU chip that contains one or two cores,
> you should also add the "-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode" option.
> **JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx3g -Xms2g -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m"**

**My Thoughts on this**

During my research I found some notes that CodeCache related problems may indicate memory leak problems, when there is a programming failure, in which the result is that the garbage collector can't empty the cache.
This **might** be possible and sadly I don't have the source code of the library in which I read the pdf. But on the other hand I have no problems in reading a 650 pages pdf on my desktop pc on a local tomcat (quadcore, 4x 3.0ghz, also 4g ram) and this confuses me.

Could it be that this is just a tomcat problem that can get solved if I use another server for deployment, like glassfish?

Can anyone help me or provide any ideas or suggestions? Maybe I did some configuration wrong? I'm not that experienced in working with tomcat or other servers, so any help is really welcome.

Thanks a lot for every answer and thought that you're sharing with me.

Comment: looks like an issue with java 7. See http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1250581-minecraft-crashes-after-java-7/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But did you post the correct link? Where is the information that relates your posted link with my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to switch from Tomcat to Glassfish as application server for deploying my application.

After that switch I never re-experienced this CodeCache behaviour.

For making sure this problem is solved I also observed the java-vm running on my server (using jconsole with remote). I didn't see any suspicious behaviour anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try another JVM like JRockit where you shouldn't have this problem. If it is Tomcat - try look if it logs something about leaks in its logs - it usually does so for classloader problems.